# Error in groovy script array

Tags: groovy

In groovy script, I am setting the property value from an array as follows:

```
def CustomerNumber = [100944050,100944193,100946438];

CustomerNumber.each(){
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("customerNumber",it);
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: {"customerNumber", 100944050}
```

Comment: What is signature of `setPropertyValue` method? what parameters it takes?

Answer (score 0):

[SoapUI's WsdlTestCase](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/testcase/wsdltestcase.html) inherits [`setPropertyValue` method](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/AbstractTestPropertyHolderWsdlModelItem.html#setPropertyValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> `public void setPropertyValue(String name,
>                       String value)
>   Specified by:
>   setPropertyValue in interface TestPropertyHolder`

You need to pass two strings to that method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDocs](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/AbstractTestPropertyHolderWsdlModelItem.html#setPropertyValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), the `setPropertyValue` method takes two String arguments. So you need to convert your customer number integer to a String:

```
def customerNumber = [100944050,100944193,100946438]

customerNumber.each {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("customerNumber", it as String)
}
```